# How to allow comments on a PloneFormGen folder?

Tags: plone, ploneformgen

Is there any way to allow users to comment (i.e., have a discussion) on a ploneformgen folder? I have allowed comments for Form Folders under Type Settings, and checked "Allow comments" under the edit>settings tab of the particular Form Folder, but this doesn't work, which is weird, because this is exactly what I do to allow comments on Pages, etc. Any ideas?

Comment: I suspect that the page template used by PFG doesn't include the viewlet manager that contains the commenting viewlet. It's possible that you could fix that by customizing the template.

Answer (score 2):

I fear that PFG is not including Plone viewlets by its own.

You must probably customize the Form view and enabling the proper viewlet manager.

If you look at the plone.app.discussion source at https://github.com/plone/plone.app.discussion/blob/9a4e3718fc8ae7e6f8f229058a27092b0d121a84/plone/app/discussion/browser/configure.zcml#L108 you'll see that the comment viewlets is defined in the `plone.app.layout.viewlets.interfaces.IBelowContent` manager.

So you must re-enable this manager in your customized template, this can be enough:

```
<div tal:replace="structure provider:plone.belowcontentbody" />
```

Put this after the main content. As side effects, other viewlet in this new manager can be displayed, in that case use CSS to hide them.

Comment: Thanks, keul. Could you give me any additional pointers on how to do this? (Sorry, I'm a recent convert from Drupal.)

Comment: I put more info in the answer itself

Comment: Hmm... I tried that, but it didn't work. I've also tried something else, which seems promising, but I'll describe it in a new answer.